# How to get two a normal string and NSMutableString on a single UILabel Text?

Tags: ios, string, swift, uilabel, nsmutablestring

I wanted to get a single UILabel Text to be modified as given below.

[image]

How can get it done using NSMutableString or UILabel's attributedText property?  Help Appreciated.

Note: The Name 'John Doe' is a user account name derived from API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this example, add your appropriate `Attribute`.

```
let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Welcome John Doe")
text.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "YourFont", size: 18)!, range: NSMakeRange(8, text.characters.count - 8))
label.attributedText = text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attributed string:

```
let text = "Welcome John Doe"
let textWithColor = "John Doe"
let range = text.rangeOfString(textWithColor)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.orangeColor() , range: range)

label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified Ronit's Answer and shared below.

```
var userNameString:String?

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        self.makeAttributedUserNameTitleLabelText()
    }
    func makeAttributedUserNameTitleLabelText()
    {
        userNameString = "John Doe"
        let text = "Welcome  "+userNameString!
        let range =  NSMakeRange(8, text.characters.count - 8)
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.orangeColor(), range: range)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Bold", size: 14)!, range: range)
        self.userNameTitleLabel.attributedText = attributedString

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
info.name = "John Doe" //which come from api

let nameValue = "Welcome " + "\(info.name!)" 

let bSerString = "\(info.name!)" 

let nameAttribt = NSMutableAttributedString(string: nameValue)
let bSRange = nameValue.rangeOfString(bSerString as String)

nameAttribt.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 14)!, range: bSRange)

nameAttribt.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.orangeColor(), range: bSRange)

self.lblName.attributedText = nameAttribt
```